# Detect distinct populations in irregular time series

Tags: time-series, clustering

I have two distinct classes, A and B both with property X. At irregular intervals I receive a measurement of X, without knowledge of whether it is a measurement from A or B. The true value of X for A and B changes over time.

What I want is a way of determining whether each measurement is of A or B.
An example may look like the below:
[image]

Where I'd want to classify each point as belonging to either A (Red) or B (Blue) like below:
[image]

A few specific points. I'm looking to solve the problem with only two populations (A & B). A is always greater than B, however at times the difference between them may be less than the error of the measurements.

My first thought would be some sort of clustering, however the euclidean distance of the points is not appropriate for a time series. Is this a common problem, or should I be looking into custom adaptions of clustering methods? My main issue is knowing where to start looking for a solution.

Comment: This is an interesting question. One clarification: is it a given that each observation of $X$ has equal probability of coming from $A$ and $B$?

Comment: No, it may be that 80% of observations come from A, for example.

Comment: This is a problem of nonlinear filtering. Should the result (a probability of being "A") be obtained offline, with a delay, or at the time of reception? What about the two timeseries when the observations are correctly labelled?

Comment: Ideally at the time of reception. Are you suggesting two separate processes then, the first to update the estimate the true X value for A and B, and then one to assign the latest observed measurement to either A or B?

Comment: Rather than a "hard" assignation,  you can use an estimate probability $p(t | s)$ that the source of the event $t$ is "A" given all the observations up to time $s$. This is quite similar to the problem solved by "Markov Switching regime" models.